# How to attach contentversion to record in Javascript

Tags: javascript, attachment, contentversion, fileupload

I am working on a solution to avoid to surpass the viewstate limit when uploading a file. Currently with javascript I create a record and create a contentversion but the contentversion is not attached to the record. What am i missing

Javascript

```
    <apex:page   showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0"  action="{!addMore}">
    <script type="text/javascript">__sfdcSessionId = '{!$Api.Session_Id}';</script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>Upload Files using XMLHttpRequest - Minimal</title>
    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File 1 to Upload</label><br />
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload1" onchange="fileSelected()"/>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File 2 to Upload</label><br />
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload2" onchange="fileSelected()"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <input type="button" onclick="CreateObjSF()" value="Upload" />
        </div>
  </form>
        <script language="JavaScript">

            function fileSelected() {
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
            if (file) {
                var fileSize = 0;
                if (file.size > (36 * 1024 * 1024)) {
                    alert('File too large, greater than 36MB');
                    return;
                }
                if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
                    fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
                else
                    fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

                document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
                document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
                document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
            }
        }

    function CreateObjSF() {
    var objectSF         = new sforce.SObject('Career__c');
    objectSF.Name        = 'Test123';
    objectSF.Function__c    = false;
    objectSF.Country__c = 'filetype';
    objectSF.Area__c       = 'filecontent';
    objectSF.Job_Posting__c = 'a011X000001EoLJQA0';
    objectSF.Status__c = 'New';
    objectSF.RecordTypeId = '0121t000000QZWUAA4';
    var results = sforce.connection.create([objectSF]);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].getBoolean("success")) {
                    alert('New Career record created: ' + results[i].id);
                      uploadFile(results[i].id);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Failed:' + results[i]);

                }
            }
    }

             function uploadFile() {

            alert('LETS UPLOAD: ');
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload1').files[0];
             alert(file.name);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = loaded;
            reader.onerror = errorHandler;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        }
        function uploadContentVersion(filename, filecontent,parentId) {
             alert('TRY content: ' + filename);
            var contentVersion          = new sforce.SObject('ContentVersion');
            contentVersion.pathOnClient = filename;
            contentVersion.origin       = 'H'; 
            contentVersion.VersionData  = filecontent;
            contentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId = parentId;
            var results = sforce.connection.create([contentVersion]);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].getBoolean("success")) {
                    alert('New ContentVersion record created:' + results[i].id);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Failed:' + results[i]);

                }
            }
        }
        function loaded(evt) {
            for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
                var filename = document.getElementById('fileToUpload' + [i]).files[0].name;
                var fileContent = String(evt.target.result);
                fileContent = fileContent.substr(fileContent.indexOf(',') + 1);
                uploadContentVersion(filename, fileContent);  
            }
        }

        function errorHandler(evt) {
            if (evt.target.error.name == 'NotReadableError') {
                alert('File could not be read');
            }
            else {
                alert(evt.target.error);
            }
        }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i guess we also create a record for contentdocumentlink to attach it to records

Comment: @User6670 this is not needed when creating trough apex controller so why should we with javascript?

Comment: @User6670 Ps. If I hardcode the Id it gets attached to the record

Comment: you want the file to be attached to Career__c record right?

Comment: @User6670  Yes the record which is created by CreateObjSF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe  we need contentdocumentlink to attach files to records you can run the following code where we create a contentdocumentlink record in last which attach the document with record created.

```
 <apex:page   showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0"  action="{!addMore}">
    <script type="text/javascript">__sfdcSessionId = '{!$Api.Session_Id}';</script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/48.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>Upload Files using XMLHttpRequest - Minimal</title>
    <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File 1 to Upload</label><br />
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload1" onchange="fileSelected()"/>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File 2 to Upload</label><br />
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload2" onchange="fileSelected()"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <input type="button" onclick="CreateObjSF()" value="Upload" />
        </div>
  </form>
        <script language="JavaScript">
var ids='';
            function fileSelected() {
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
            if (file) {
                var fileSize = 0;
                if (file.size > (36 * 1024 * 1024)) {
                    alert('File too large, greater than 36MB');
                    return;
                }
                if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
                    fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
                else
                    fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

                document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
                document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
                document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
            }
        }

    function CreateObjSF() {
   var objectSF         = new sforce.SObject('Career__c');
    objectSF.Name        = 'Test123';
    objectSF.Function__c    = false;
    objectSF.Country__c = 'filetype';
    objectSF.Area__c       = 'filecontent';
    objectSF.Job_Posting__c = 'a011X000001EoLJQA0';
    objectSF.Status__c = 'New';
    objectSF.RecordTypeId = '0121t000000QZWUAA4';;

    var results = sforce.connection.create([objectSF]);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].getBoolean("success")) {
                    alert('New Career record created: ' + results[i].id);
                    this.ids=results[i].id;
                      uploadFile(results[i].id);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Failed:' + results[i]);

                }
            }
    }

             function uploadFile() {

            alert('LETS UPLOAD: ');
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload1').files[0];
             alert(file.name);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = loaded;
            reader.onerror = errorHandler;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
        }
        function uploadContentVersion(filename, filecontent,parentId) {
             alert('TRY content: ' + filename);
            var contentVersion          = new sforce.SObject('ContentVersion');
            contentVersion.pathOnClient = filename;
            contentVersion.origin       = 'H'; 
            contentVersion.VersionData  = filecontent;


            var results = sforce.connection.create([contentVersion]);


            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var condoc =  sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = '"+ results[i].id +"'")

                if (results[i].getBoolean("success")) {

                    var contentDocumentLink          = new sforce.SObject('ContentDocumentLink');
                     contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId =condoc.records.ContentDocumentId;
    contentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = this.ids;
    contentDocumentLink.ShareType = 'I'; // Inferred permission
                    console.log(contentDocumentLink)
                    var results2 = sforce.connection.create([contentDocumentLink]);
                    console.log(results2);

                    alert('New ContentVersion record created:' + results[i].id);

                }
                else {
                    alert('Failed:' + results[i]);

                }
            }
        }
        function loaded(evt) {
            for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
                var filename = document.getElementById('fileToUpload' + [i]).files[0].name;
                var fileContent = String(evt.target.result);
                fileContent = fileContent.substr(fileContent.indexOf(',') + 1);
                uploadContentVersion(filename, fileContent);  
            }
        }

        function errorHandler(evt) {
            if (evt.target.error.name == 'NotReadableError') {
                alert('File could not be read');
            }
            else {
                alert(evt.target.error);
            }
        }
</script>
</apex:page>
```